# Setting form field value via javascript in webforms framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a grid and form element I read grid from webservice and fill it. What I want to do is there is a button column on grid when user clicks button I want to set the value of firm name field of the form section. Our framework is webforms . I got the firmName from grid but I could not set form section's field. The problem is about the id. Id is specified at runtime the id in the form is txtFirmaAdi but ı could not set it in js. Thank you, my script is as follows:

```
 function callme(e) {
           
            var tds = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td');
            var text = $('[id$="txtFirmaAdi"]');  
          
            text.value = tds[1].innerHTML.trim();
            text.value = "DEneme";
```

My form aspx is as follows:

```
           <div class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">İşyeri Adı</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirmaAdi" CssClass="input-xlarge" MaxLength="220"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if the problem is unpredictable id at runtime, you can add the property clientidmode="static" to the textbox to assure the id is same both at server-side and client-side.

Comment: thank you clientidmode="static"  solved

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I find the easy way to do this is to pass the button name to the js code and work from that.

The HTML standard is to NOT have controls or buttons etc. with the same id given.

So, when you drop in controls to the GridView, they can (and do) will have an "id" that you assigned, but then due to multiple rows, then in most cases, the control will be re-named, and prefixed with the GridView ID, and then suffixed with the row number (starting at 0).

so, say this simple grid view, along with a row click button like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
    Width="45%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H Templated">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("HotelName")  %>'  >
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                    CssClass="btn"
                    OnClientClick="myedit(this);return false;"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<script>
    function myedit(btn) {
        var txtHotelc = "#" + btn.id.replace("_cmdEdit_", "_txtHotel_")
        var txtHotel = $(txtHotelc)
        alert("Hotel name from row = " + txtHotel.text())

        // get cells collection, NON templated columns
        var myrow = btn.closest('tr')
        alert(myrow.cells[0].innerText)
    }


</script>
```

Code behind to load the grid view:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                                WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY HotelName")
    GVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, there are 2 use cases:

I want to get a templated control (label, text box, check box etc.)

Or

I want to get a cells collection item (data bound columns).

For templated controls (asp.net controls), then they will have as noted that number scheme applied to them (GridViewName_ControlName_RowNumber).

So, I just do a simple replace on the button ID (make sure that is a server-side button).

For the cells collection, non templated, then we select the current row, and then use the cells collection as per above.