# Setting date field of grid to form field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a grid and form. In grid I have enddate field. I want to set form's enddate field grid's end date when row is selected. I could set text firm Name field . But I couldn't set end date. I didn't understand why is this so. Thank you.

My form data is as follows:

```
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Başlama / Bitiş Tarihi</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <iskurDateTimeBoxes:IskurDateBox ID="dtGirisTarih" runat="server" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<iskurDateTimeBoxes:IskurDateBox ID="dtCikisTarih" runat="server" clientidmode="static"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my script is as follows:

```
        function callme(e) {
           
            var tds = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td');

            document.getElementById('txtFirmaAdi').value = tds[2].innerHTML.trim();
            document.getElementById('dtCikisTarih').value = tds[7].innerHTML.trim();
           

        }
```

In the formaspx file my code is as follows:

```
      <iskurControls:IskurGridView runat="server"
                ID="ctlGridSgkTecrube"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                EmptyDataText="Tecrübe Bilginiz Bulunmamaktadır."
                EnableViewState="true"
                CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed text-small">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seç">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAktar" runat="server" Text="Aktar" CommandName="AktarRow"  class = "inp" OnClientClick="return callme(this)"  />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ISYERISICILNO" HeaderText="İşyeri Sicil No" >
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ISYERIADI" HeaderText="İşyeri Adı" >
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MESLEKKODU" HeaderText="Meslek Kodu">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MESLEK" HeaderText="Meslek">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SURE" HeaderText="Süre">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BASLANGICTARIHI" HeaderText="Baş Tar">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BITISTARIHI" HeaderText="Bit Tar">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="grid-PagerStyle"></PagerStyle>
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="grid-SelectedRowStyle"></SelectedRowStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-HeaderStyle"></HeaderStyle>
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="grid-EditRowStyle"></EditRowStyle>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grid-AlternatingRowStyle"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="grid-FooterStyle"></FooterStyle>
                <RowStyle CssClass="grid-RowStyle"></RowStyle>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="grid-EmptyRow" />
            </iskurControls:IskurGridView>
```

Comment: When is `callme()` executed and what is passed to it? It seems like I have seen several versions of this question today. What is considered a row and how does one "select" a row?

Comment: See my answer to your previous question. I don't recommend using static, since that breaks the HTML rule of having more then one control with the same ID. Simple use the previous answer I gave to pluck out that templated control. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971918/setting-form-field-value-via-javascript-in-webforms-framework/76972894#76972894

Comment: Hi Albert; even though I set static I could not set date field from grid.

Comment: Hi mykaf; I added that part to the question

Comment: Since you seem to be having javascript problems, and javascript interacts with html, the *rendered* html would be more helpful than the asp.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you can get/grab controls from the one row using this approach:

So, say this markup:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
        Width="45%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingDate" HeaderText="Booking date" 
                 DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                        CssClass="btn"
                        OnClientClick="myedit(this);return false;"
                        />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
    <h3>Hotel</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <h3>booking date</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBdate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>



    <script>
        function myedit(btn) {
            // get cells collection, NON templated columns
            var myrow = btn.closest('tr')
            $('#txtHotel').val(myrow.cells[3].innerText)
            $('#txtBdate').val(myrow.cells[5].innerText)
        }


    </script>
```

Code behind to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                                WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY HotelName")
    GVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, from the client-side button click, we get/grab the row, and then simple set the 2 text box values (using .val()).

I of course assume jQuery in above.